# Auto-fill from a list row with same title

Tags: powerapps

I have an app that a user types in a site name and a tells us about the different areas within that site. As part of this, they have to give the address of the site. Each site input creates a new row with the SP list.

I was wondering if there is a way to auto-fill the address text boxes when the user is inputting the details of a different area within the same site. They have the option to select an existing site name and create a new area for it (and a new row in the list) but this just gives consistency of site name rather than saving the user time typing in the same address for multiple entries.

Is there a way to pull through the address info from the first site entry for when they are creating a new form (telling us about a different area) at the same site.

If the site already exists in the list (has an entry) then they select ot from a combo box, if it doesn't they type the site name into a textbox.

So could there be a way of saying that if the combo box has been used, then the address textboxes on the next page are auto-filled, and of the text box has been used, the address textboxes are empty to be types in.

Have tried using on select function in drop down but can't use against a table

Comment: What I understood is that, a single site can have multiple area of work and for each area of work you want to create a new SP record item. If user put a site name then in combobox all associated area should be populated but if user want to put a new area there should be text files. Ryt?